# Where should DataProvider.php go?

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, magento2.3.3, data-provider

I'm seeing examples of putting the DataProvider class in the following location:

`[YourNameSpace]\[YourModule]\Model\[ComponentName]\DataProvider`

However, the documentation makes me believe it should live in this location:

`[YourNameSpace]\[YourModule]\Ui\DataProvider\[YourComponentName]\DataProvider`

Are both of these acceptable locations or do they have different purposes? I'm reading through the documentation but unfortunately it really just doesn't provide a solid example (unless I'm missing it).

Answer (score 0):

The First way

```
YourNameSpace]\[YourModule]\Model\[ComponentName]\DataProvider
```

Makes the most sense to me

For example

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactToDb/blob/master/Model/Contact/DataProvider.php

I see where confusion has come

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactToDb/blob/82c3748d597cdaaed57f73241cc6502e1c2ea9fd/etc/di.xml#L12

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
```

But this is a framework model and used in the UI grid